# My app's Service keeps being killed

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a pool of AsyncTasks which pass state data back to the service that executed them, but they keep being killed by Android.

I can't use an IntentService because the Service is keeping track of State used by UI and AsyncTasks.

How do I:
1) keep the service from being killed
2) Replace either service or AsyncTask with something better for this use case?

Comment: There is nothing that can prevent your app's process from being terminated when the app is not in the foreground. Android will simply reclaim its resources when they are needed by something of higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). Android OS can kill service if it is running short on resources, but it will always spare foreground service.

> The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low
>   and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user
>   focus. If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus,
>   then it's less likely to be killed, and if the service is declared to
>   run in the [foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) (discussed later), then it will almost never be
>   killed.

Note: Another thing you should also consider

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the
>   service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
>   process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your
>   service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations
>   (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread
>   within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you
>   will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and
>   the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction
>   with your activities.